# String Values with Special Characters are getting trim while data import in Dynamics 365

Tags: csv, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-365, data-import

I've below records in CSV to import in Dynamics CRM. But they are getting trimmed and not complete is getting import in Dynamics CRM.

I tried to create records using C# Console application, SSIS Packages but still no luck to get import all records exactly what I am having in CSV.

Please share your thoughts to import them sucssfully.

**CSV**

```
Name
Show - Barter Discount
Show - Expired Product Discount - (> 25K or < 35K) AND (>25% or < 30%)
Show - Expired Product & Normal Discount - (>150K >30%) & (<500K)
Show - Expired Product & Normal Discount - >500k
Show - Expired Product & Normal Discount <150k or <= 30%
Show - Expired Product with Barter Discount
Show - Expiry Products With Normal & Barter Discounts - <150k  <=30%
Show - Expiry Products With Normal & Barter Discounts - >500k
Show - Expiry Products With Normal & Barter Discounts - 150K-500K  <=30%
Show - Extending Contract
Show - Extending Early Bird Pricelist Product
Show - Extending Loyalty Pricelist Product
Show - Normal Discount - (>  150K or > 30%) AND (<=  500K)
Show - Normal Discount - >  500K
Show - Normal Discount - Upto 150k AND <= 30%
Show - Normal Discount & Barter Discount - 150k-500k  >30%
Show - Normal Discount & Barter Discount - Upto 150k or <= 30%
Show - Normal Discount & Barter Discount > 500k
Show - Order Amendment Discount  <50k
Show - Order Amendment Discount  >150k
Show - Order Amendment Discount  >50k <150k
```

Comment: Perhaps a obvious question - the field this data is going into, is the field length big enough to hold the data?! Have you tried to add the offending data into the system manually? - this would be my first thing to test out..

Comment: Yes, the field length is 100. Also, I am able to add these lines manually

Answer (score 1):

I just imported your csv data into one of my instance and it worked fine for me.
[image]

Make sure you have below setting when you import

[image]

and here further setting

[image]

Comment: could you add some more information, screenshots of your steps performed. Also do you have any Plugin/Workflow on name field for your entity?

Comment: no plugin or workflow, if I directly type in the field I can add the exact value but when it comes to import, I couldn't. 1. Save the file as CSV 2. Import the file 3. Select the Field delimiter as Semicolon 4. Data delimiter as non.

Comment: can you share your input file?

Comment: Here is the file, Is the issue resolved?

http://www.filedropper.com/csvtoimport

Comment: @MohsinA. If this helps could you please mark it as solved. will help others as well.